# GPS get latitude longitude using standard method?

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to get the location of the device, but the code

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 String provider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

 myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0,
 myLocationListener);

 Location lastLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

"lastLocation" returns null. if restart the device, the same null is obtained. is there any other standard way to obtain latitude and longitude from the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive your location asynchonously in your `myLocationListener`. After that (when listener is invoked) `gatLastKnownLocation` will return something not null.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) is a complete example of how it should be implemented.